# Trying to save an app generated file in the user visible Download directory

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

Im generating a local file & use the following code to save the file.

```
if (transactions.isNotEmpty()) {
   var dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
   var file = File(dir, "transactions.csv")
   if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile()
   transactions.forEach {
       var outputString = "${it.transID},${it.transDate},${it.transDesc},${it.transAmt},${it.transCat},${it.transAccnt},${it.transNotes} \\n"
       file.writeText(outputString)
       Log.i("Output", outputString)
       }
}
```

The above results in a "Permission Denied Exception".
If i change the Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory to getExternalFileDir()

```
if (transactions.isNotEmpty()) {
   var dir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
   var file = File(dir, "transactions.csv")
   if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile()
   transactions.forEach {
       var outputString = "${it.transID},${it.transDate},${it.transDesc},${it.transAmt},${it.transCat},${it.transAccnt},${it.transNotes} \\n"
       file.writeText(outputString)
       Log.i("Output", outputString)
       }
}
```

The file gets stored in "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.anand.expensecalculator/files/Documents".

I have the "`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`" already set in my manifest.

How do I access the "Downloads" to store the file?

Comment: You need to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. You need to also request that at runtime on Android 6.0+. On Android 10, you need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on the `<application>` element in the manifest.

Comment: I already had the ```WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE```. I tried the ```android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"```. Still the same issue. my file still gets buried! Im not able to see the file in "Downloads"